# Why would an object be deformed by subsurf and differ from the 3D view when rendered?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to render a scene that contains a bullet and an empty cartridge in Blender. However, when I render it using Cycles render it warps horribly.

Scene screenshot:

[image: scene]

Rendered preview in the 3d View:
[image: preview]

Rendered result:
[image: render]

Comment: What do you mean by "warping"? What isn't as expected exactly? Check the modifier stack for the object, probably there're some modifiers which have different values for preview and final render. Some jargon is inevitable when dealing with fields like 3D, the only way to explain is to use correct words

Comment: The 'jargon' you ask us not to use is nothing more but the correct language to talk about the subject. Without it we will not be able to communicate. You must learn the correct terminology in order to talk about it. There is no other way.

Comment: In the subsurf modifier settings, there are two strenght setting: One for viewport and one for render. Make sure they are the same and that the modifier is enabled to be displayed in both render and viewport (by clicking the camera/monitor icons at the to of the modifier)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a closer look at the modifier tab in the Properties Editor (you can find explanations of the terms I use [in the documetnation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/properties_editor.html)) you will see that modifiers have these camera and eye icons. They define if the modifier is visible in the viewport(that includes rendered preview mode) and in the final render. This makes it possible to view less complicated scene in the viewport and therefore be able to interact with it without lag and then have a lot more detail in the rendered result that might not be interactive and smooth if viewed in the viewport while working. You have one modifier that is only visible in rendered result. If you do not want to have it, you should remove it completely by pressing the x icon in the right-most end of the icon row.

[image]

Comment: It's called a modifier in this case a Subsurf or Subdivision Surface modifier. Properties in Blender are all the parameters that you can input like for example the amount of subdivisions or even that visibility button toggles the viewport visibility property of the modifier. I know the language might seem insignificant, but it really gets confusing very quickly if you are using the incorrect words in this context so it's a really good idea to make an effort to notice the exact language while you are learning.